# Laravel: I want to display the User score data together with joint tables of user and organization

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, postman, backend

I want to display my user score data together with the joint tables of user and organization. I also want to display the data using the User Score id.

**userScore Model:**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class userScore extends Model
{
    public $table = "user_scores";
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id'); #if column not found indicate the column name
    }
}
```

**Users Model:**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Models;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function socialAccount(){
        return $this->hasMany(SocialAccount::class);
    }

    
    public function organizations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\organizations','id'); #if column not found indicate the column name
    }

    public function userScores(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\userScore');
    }

}
```

**Organization Model:**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class organizations extends Model
{
    public $table = "organizations";
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users(){
        // return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_id'); #if column not found indicate the column name
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User'); #if column not found indicate the column name
    }

}
```

**Here's the UserScoreController:**

```
      public function userScoreByUser(Request $request, $id){
   
        $userScores = userScore::find($id);
        if(is_null($userScores)){
            return response()->json('User Score not found!', 401);
        }

        $user_scores = DB::table('user_scores')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('organizations', 'organizations.id', '=', 'organizations.id')
            ->select('user_scores.*','users.name','users.email','organizations.org_title')
            ->get()
            ;

            $users = userScore::with('users')->get();
        return response(['message'=>"User Score displayed successfully", 'UserScore'=>$userScores,],200);

    }
}
```

**Here's the API Route:**

```
Route::resource('userScore','App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserScoreCRUDController');
Route::get('userScoreByOrg/{user_scores_id}','App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserScoreCRUDController@userScoreByUser');
```

I'm also having a problem displaying the data, it happens when I get the data or try to display the data in postman, it returns the user score data with users but not with the joint tables where the organization name should be visible.

**Here's the example response:**

```
{
    "message": "User Score displayed successfully",
    "UserScore": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "quiz_id": 1,
            "module_id": 1,
            "number_of_correct_answers": 20,
            "created_at": "2021-08-12T04:18:18.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-12T04:18:18.000000Z",
            "time_started": null,
            "time_finished": null,
            "users": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Carl Joshua Lalongbilang",
                "email": "carllalongbilang28@gmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": "2021-07-31T03:31:23.000000Z",
                "created_at": "2021-07-31T03:04:59.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-07-31T03:31:23.000000Z",
                "provider": null,
                "provider_id": null,
                "avatar": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 3,
            "quiz_id": 1,
            "module_id": 1,
            "number_of_correct_answers": 12,
            "created_at": "2021-08-12T04:29:46.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-12T04:29:46.000000Z",
            "time_started": null,
            "time_finished": null,
            "users": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Carl Joshua Lalongbilang",
                "email": "carllalongbilang282@gmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-08-05T17:16:42.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-05T17:16:42.000000Z",
                "provider": null,
                "provider_id": null,
                "avatar": null
            }
        },
```

It also didn't display the data by userScore ID.

I'm currently studying Laravel for the first time So, any kind of help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using join, have you tried it like this?

```
public function userScoreByUser(Request $request, $id){

    $userScore = userScore::where('id',$id)->with('users')->with('users.organizations')->first();
    if(is_null($userScore)){
        return response()->json('User Score not found!', 401);
    }

    return response(['message'=>"User Score displayed successfully", 'UserScore'=>$userScore,],200);

}
```

Comment: Bro thank you so much!! this actually works